# How To Grab Parts of Specific Color from one Image and Draw Them into Another Image Using OpenCV Python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have two pictures called **pic1.jpg** and **pic2.jpg**, and these two pictures are of the same size (same width, same height).

I want to take those parts whose color is yellow (rgb=255,255,0) from pic1, and then draw them to pic2 at the same position.

How can I do this via opencv-python? I googled and tried below code, but it doesn't work.

```
image1 = cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('pic2.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# only want the yellow parts
lower_color = np.array([0, 255, 255])
upper_color = np.array([0, 255, 255])

# 
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)

# add them to image2
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image2, image2, mask=mask)

cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', result)
```

Comment: You're working in HSV, and HSV triple of `[0, 255, 255]` is pure red, not yellow.

Comment: (0 degrees being red, 255 saturation, 255 value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't use `cv2.bitwise_and` for replacing masked pixels in `image2` with pixels from `image1`.
In C++ we may use [mat::copyTo](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a626fe5f96d02525e2604d2ad46dd574f) with mask for doing that, but in Python, we can't use `copyTo`, because it cannot be used with NumPy arrays.

We may solve it using something like `result = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.bitwise_and(image1, mask), cv2.bitwise_and(image2, cv2.bitwise_not(mask)))`.
But using NumPy logical indexing seems more elegant.

Note:
As commented, `[0, 255, 255]` is red in HSV.
We don't have to convert to HSV for finding yellow pixels.
If we do, the yellow value is `[30, 255, 255]` in HSV.

---

For applying logical indexing or bitwise operations we have to make mask the same dimensions as the images.
Using OpenCV: `mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` replicates the mask to 3 axes.

---

Code sample:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('pic2.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

cv2.imwrite('hsv.png', hsv)

# Only want the yellow parts. Yellow in HSV equls [30, 255, 255]
lower_color = np.array([28, 250, 250])
upper_color = np.array([32, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Convert maks to 3D array - as np.concatenate((mask,mask,mask))

#result = cv2.bitwise_or(cv2.bitwise_and(image1, mask), cv2.bitwise_and(image2, cv2.bitwise_not(mask)))  # Pure OpenCV solution.

result = image2
result[mask==255] = image1[mask==255]  # Use logical indexing for replacing the masked pixels in image2 with pixels from image1.

cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', result)

# Write mask for testing
cv2.imwrite('mask.jpg', mask)
```

---

The following images were used for testing:

`image1`:
[image]

`image2`:
[image]

---

`result`:
[image]

`mask`:
[image]

---

### Update:

Code sample without converting to HSV color space:

Conversion to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is useful for finding larger range of yellow (yellowish) colored pixels.
Example: Searching pixels with Hue=30, Saturation in range [100, 255] and Value in range [30, 255] returns large range of yellow pixels (dark yellow, bright yellow...).

When looking for pure bright yellow, we may apply `cv2.inRange` to BGR color format, and search for pixels with Blue=0, Green=255, Red=255.
The example uses a bit wider range `[0, 250, 250]` to `[5, 255, 255]` (mainly because the JPEG compression modifies the original values).

Code sample, without converting to HSV:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread('pic1.jpg')
image2 = cv2.imread('pic2.jpg')

# Only want the yellow parts. Yellow in BGR equls [0, 255, 255]
lower_color = np.array([0, 250, 250])
upper_color = np.array([5, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(image1, lower_color, upper_color)  # Apply inRange to image1 in BGR color format
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # Convert maks to 3D array - as np.concatenate((mask,mask,mask))

result = image2
result[mask==255] = image1[mask==255]  # Use logical indexing for replacing the masked pixels in image2 with pixels from image1.

cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', result)
```

Comment: so useful comments and so detailed! I have only one question:  using your code, I almost succeeded, but why the yellow parts  had some black holes in them after being drawn to pic2? these corresponding parts are continuous yellow area in pic1.

Comment: another thing to mention, I don't need the hsv. I don't know they are necessary or not. if you think they are not then please help remove them, actually I know the RGB data more than the hsv. I use them only because they are used in some example from google pages and seems to solve my issue.

Comment: The "holes" are [parts that are not yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRPjX.png) in `image1`. I updated my answer - added an example without conversion to HSV.